# php file upload: use of unlink in a list to delete an element from the server

Tags: php, file-upload

I have this php to upload a file, I want add a button at the right of each element of the list where if I click on I delete the element from the list and from the server. Is it possible? Thanks

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select a file to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Load" name="submit">
</form>

<div>

    <?php
    $dir    = 'up/';
    $files = scandir($dir);
    echo 'uploaded files<br><hr>';
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($files as $key)
    {
        if ($i>2)
        {
            $j = $i-2;
            echo $j."&nbsp&nbsp<a href='up/".$key."'>".$key."</a><hr>";
        }
        $i++;
    }
    echo ' ';
    ?>

</div>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo '<center><h1>upload succesful!</h1></center>';
    $structure = 'up/';
    $target_file = $structure.basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts on your own to make the deleting button and code as you want ? If so, then we would like to see it, and help you out, because almost everything is possible, and so is the button to delete the file, but try on your own first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) the files that you need to do it.

**Here are the easy steps for you ;)**

**Step 1 :** Create an  anchor tag which gives the path of the image/file

`<a href='index.php?delete=up/<?php echo $key?>'>Delete Now</a>`

**Step 2 :** On clicking the anchor tag, the page will be redirect to itself with the file's name

**Step 3 :** Get the file and unlink (delete) it

`unset($_GET['delete']);`

**Step 4 :** Refresh the page once to have a fresh list of files.

`header("Refresh:0; url=".$url);`

Here's the [Eval](https://eval.in/393030) for you and
Here's the code that you need to have

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select a file to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Load" name="submit">
</form>

<div>

    <?php
    error_reporting(0);
    session_start();
    $dir    = 'up/';
    $files = scandir($dir);
    echo 'uploaded files<br><hr>';
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($files as $key)
    {
        if ($i>2)
        {
            $j = $i-2;
            echo $j."&nbsp&nbsp<a href='up/".$key."'>".$key."</a>";
    if (isset($_GET['delete'])) 
    {
        unlink($_GET['delete']);

        $_SESSION['delete'] = $_GET['delete'];
        unset($_GET['delete']);
        $url = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].http_build_query($_GET);
        header("Refresh:0; url=".$url);
    }
?>
   <a href='index.php?delete=up/<?php echo $key?>'>Delete Now</a>
            <hr>
            <?php
        }
        $i++;
    }

    ?>

</div>
</body>
</html>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo '<center><h1>upload succesful!</h1></center>';
    $structure = 'up/';
    $target_file = $structure.basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Sulthan Allaudeen, you're a really good teacher! I've improved a little this code (looking at your teaching) and I added another 
`header("Refresh:0; url=".$url); ` in the last php, in order to refresh also the list of files every time I add a new one!

Comment: @Luigi You're welcome :) That's really good to hear. And i expected the another header refresh part from you and you have got the point. Cheers ! :)

Comment: Don't be so proud of me: I tried to extend this unlink to a more complex table of images but I failed!! ;)
I made a new question if you can take a look i'll be grateful! http://stackoverflow.com/q/31235084/4842333

Comment: Cool, Let me look at there ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, bind the element_id with the button that you want to display at the end of each list.

On button click, send an HTTP request to server with the element id and delete that element record from the server.

Now request newest data and update. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You're just need make ajax code with Web Service's (REST) for remove the file from the server.
Or- you can make "if" before that file upload to server