# Add to an uploaded images table the choice of deleting one of the images

Tags: php, html-table, unlink

I have a page where I can upload some images, see the list of images loaded in a table. I want to add the chance to delete one of the images in the list from the server. I tried but something in this code is not working. Any help?

```
<html>
<body> 
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select a photo to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Load" name="submit">
</form>

<?php 
$dir = 'up/'; 
$files = scandir($dir);
$maxnum = count($files); 
?> 

<table class="thumbnail"> 
<?php $i = 2; 
for ($j = 0; $j < $maxnum; $j++) { 
echo '<tr>'; 
$k = $i + 5; 
for ($i; $i < $k; $i++) { 
If ($i == $maxnum) { break; } 
echo '<td><a href="'.$dir.$files{$i}.'"><img src="'.$dir.$files{$i}.'"></a> </td>';
 if (isset($_GET['delete'])) 
    {
        unlink($_GET['delete']);

        $_SESSION['delete'] = $_GET['delete'];
        unset($_GET['delete']);
        $url = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].http_build_query($_GET);
        header("Refresh:0; url=".$url);
    }
?>
   <a href='index.php?delete=up/<?php echo $key?>' id="button">Delete now</a> 
} 
echo "</tr>"; 
} ?> 
</table> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
echo '<center><h1>succesfully loaded!</h1></center>';
$structure = 'up/';
$target_file = $structure.basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
}
?>
```

Comment: You wanted to display the image and show the `Delete Now` option at same time ?

Comment: Yes, because with images the name couldn't be very descriptive of the image, so to add the choice of delete an img I thought it's better to have all the images as small thumbnails and the `Delete Now` option for each one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mistakes that have done :**

1. Not closing the loop `}}` at the end
2. Not giving the proper file path `$dir.$files{$i}` in the anchor tag.

Here's the [eval](https://eval.in/393052)

**Here's the code :**

```
<html>
<body> 
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select a photo to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Load" name="submit">
</form>

<?php 
$dir = 'up/'; 
$files = scandir($dir);
$maxnum = count($files); 
?> 

<table class="thumbnail"> 
<?php $i = 2; 
for ($j = 0; $j < $maxnum; $j++) { 
echo '<tr>'; 
$k = $i + 5; 
for ($i; $i < $k; $i++) { 
If ($i == $maxnum) { break; } 
echo '<td><br><a href="'.$dir.$files{$i}.'"><img src="'.$dir.$files{$i}.'" height="50" width="50"></a> </td>';
 if (isset($_GET['delete'])) 
    {
        unlink($_GET['delete']);

        $_SESSION['delete'] = $_GET['delete'];
        unset($_GET['delete']);
        $url = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].http_build_query($_GET);
        header("Refresh:0; url=".$url);
    }
?> 
   <a href='index.php?delete=<?php echo $dir.$files{$i}?>' id="button">Delete now</a> 


</table> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
echo '<center><h1>succesfully loaded!</h1></center>';
$structure = 'up/';
$target_file = $structure.basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
}
}}
?>
```

**Note :**

The first anchor tag might look at left aligned. It's just a design issue ;)

Comment: Oh, That's okay, Now all corrected ? and Listing of thumbnail images and deleting works as expected ?

Comment: Sure do. Design is not at all a matter and more thing to consider, Functionality alone matters for a developer  ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82432/discussion-between-sulthan-allaudeen-and-luigi).

Comment: I tried the code (this https://eval.in/393700) and I found something not working. I'm not able to fix it, I try to explain what's wrong:
-  the delete button isn't working for some images, and I can't find a common relation between the non-eraseable images (that's weird!)
- when I delete an image I have to refresh manually the page in order to make that image disappear (I tried to add a new refresh, but it messes up everything)
- also when I add an Image I have to refresh manually to see the thumbnail
- when I add an image the text succesfully loaded!appears at the side of each thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

I've found two problems: you forgot a `<?php` tag
and your delete link was wrong

So the code:

```
<html>
<body> 
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select a photo to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Load" name="submit">
</form>

<?php 
$dir = 'up/'; 
$files = scandir($dir);
$maxnum = count($files); 
?> 

<table class="thumbnail"> 
<?php $i = 2; 
for ($j = 0; $j < $maxnum; $j++) { 
echo '<tr>'; 
$k = $i + 5; 
for ($i; $i < $k; $i++) { 
If ($i == $maxnum) { break; } 
echo '<td><a href="'.$dir.$files{$i}.'"><img src="'.$dir.$files{$i}.'"></a> </td>';
 if (isset($_GET['delete'])) 
    {
        unlink($_GET['delete']);

        $_SESSION['delete'] = $_GET['delete'];
        unset($_GET['delete']);
        $url = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].http_build_query($_GET);
        header("Refresh:0; url=".$url);
    }
?>

   <a href='index.php?delete=<?php echo $dir.$files{$i}?>' id="button">Delete now</a>
<?php //<--you forgot this
} 
echo "</tr>"; 
} ?> 
</table> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
echo '<center><h1>succesfully loaded!</h1></center>';
$structure = 'up/';
$target_file = $structure.basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
}
?>
```